# Subclass PFLogInViewController to render custom UIAlertViews

Tags: ios, subclass

I am using Parse as the backend for my iOS app and I'm also using the native `PFLogInViewController` & `PFSignUpViewController` for login and signup tasks.

**Issue?**

I've customized the look of my UIAlertViews throughout the app and it turns out that Parse have hard-coded calls to UIAlertViews in their native PFLogInViewController & PFSignUpViewController implementations. An e.g. for this alert view is when the login fails due to incorrect username & password combination.

I'm wondering how I can subclass `PFLogInViewController` & `PFSignUpViewController` and implement my own custom UIAlertView class.

EDIT — Any ideas people?

Answer (score 1):

`PFLogInViewController` does not provide hooks to change this behavior. You might want to build your own custom `PFLogInViewController` subclass and override the method which display alert view when login failed.

Since PFLogInViewController's code [has been open sourced](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS), according to it the method which displays an alert view is `_loginDidFailWithError`.

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/blob/master/ParseUI/Classes/LogInViewController/PFLogInViewController.m#L382-L390

> ```
> - (void)_loginDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
>     if (_delegateExistingMethods.didFailToLogIn) {
>         [_delegate logInViewController:self didFailToLogInWithError:error];
>     }
>     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:PFLogInFailureNotification object:self];
>
>     NSString *title = NSLocalizedString(@"Login Error", @"Login error alert title in PFLogInViewController");
>     [PFUIAlertView showAlertViewWithTitle:title error:error];
> }
> ```

For example, if you like the following, you can not to display alerts when the login fails.
Define `MYLogInViewController` as subclass of `PFLogInViewController`

```
@interface MYLogInViewController : PFLogInViewController

@end

@implementation MYLogInViewController

- (void)_loginDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(logInViewController:didFailToLogInWithError:)]) {
        [self.delegate logInViewController:self didFailToLogInWithError:error];
    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:PFLogInFailureNotification object:self];

    NSString *title = NSLocalizedString(@"Login Error", @"Login error alert title in PFLogInViewController");
    //
    // Implement to display your custom alert view
    //
}

@end
```

and use it instead `PFLogInViewController`

```
MYLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[MYLogInViewController alloc] init];
logInViewController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views under "Subclassing for Full Customization".